# Failed connection to amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I can connect to my Amazon RDS MYSQL instance from the following

- EC2 instance in both command line and usin mysql workbench
- From an Excel Worksheet using the mysql driver and an odbc, on my laptop.

However from my laptop I can not connect to the instance from

- Command Line
- Mysql Workbench

TELNET TEST

```
N
 5.5.40-log</UA"%2kF☻└§\ypC@Td}fhWYmysql_native_password
connection to host lost.
```

MYSQL CMD LINE ERROR

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 2
```

CURRENT SITUATION

- I am running windows.
- I have checked the amazon service is healthy
- I have checked another internet connection.
- I have had this error before but it just sorted itself out.
- I have not been able to access MYSQL for over 24hours from cmd or
  workbench    or telnet but I can from EC2 and Excel.
- Security group settings are open to anyone. Has been like that for 1 year
- The log shows some IP failed attempts from unkown IPs, one was in China, I am in the UK.
- Secure groups have been added to the instance.

### UPDATE

It appears that I can access the RDS MYSQL server from Starbucks. This issue must relate to my internet provider at home. What could I ask the internet provider to check?

Comment: mysql is usually port 3306, not port 3309.

Comment: Did you add the secure groups to your rds instance?

Comment: Some ISP block various ports for all sorts of reasons. The easiest way for you to test whether or not your ISP is blocking mysql would be to launch a temporary RDS instance that uses a different database port and see if you can connect to it from your ISP.  I'd recommend using something like port 8080 since that's commonly used and not likely to be blocked by your ISP.  If you have two RDS instances that are configured 100% the same with only different ports and you can connect to one but not the other then it means your ISP is likely blocking it.

Comment: I've discovered that BT have opted me into sharing my IP address. https://community.bt.com/t5/Other-Broadband-Queries/Port-3306-worked-until-25-05-13-but-doesnt-anymore/td-p/874562 I have opted out. I can now connect to the instance on port 3306. I will continue testing but this may have fixed it.